# Is storm Python 3 compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, storm-orm

I haven't found any information on that topic and its [homepage](http://storm.canonical.com) doesn't mention it.

Comment: Did you try it?  What did it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With storm 0.21, it supports Python 3.

You may refer to the [release notes](https://launchpad.net/storm/trunk/0.21) for details, or more specifically, refer to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/storm/+bug/1530734) for addressing this.

Answer (score 4):

Even though planned, at the moment there is no support for Python 3, you can check it out more details about that reading this thread from the storm ml:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/storm/2009-January/000839.html

Comment: That was before the 0.14 release and a long time ago, any changes since that?

Comment: Since january i've not heard anything about the porting; at the moment if you try to install storm package v.0.14 with Python 3.0.1 the process fails while building a C extension. I didn't investigate how much effort is needed to fix that error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fully functional Python3-compatible fork of Storm that's being maintained for [Stoq](https://www.stoq.com.br); it's been under review for a while but we've not been able to [conclude the work of merging it upstream](https://code.launchpad.net/~hackedbellini/storm/py3/+merge/325182).

The [project PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stoq-dev/+archive/ubuntu/lancamentos) contains built debs, which you can pull directly from build pages like this:

- (amd64) https://launchpad.net/~romaia/+archive/ubuntu/rpi3/+build/14504969
- (i386) https://launchpad.net/~romaia/+archive/ubuntu/rpi3/+build/14504972

Comment: Thanks for updating this old question. Btw. the certificate for the link https://stoq.com.br is invalid. It's probably best to fix the certificate, or change the link to https://www.stoq.com.br

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; it was the redirect from stoq.com.br that ended up broken in a letsencrypt migration! It's fixed now, modulo DNS propagation.